# Open Layers 3 - Initialize Draw Interaction with first node on LineString

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a map where a user can choose some object/feature on the map and draw a line to another object/feature. When the user selects the feature i would like do add a draw interaction and already set the first point to the selected feature without the user having to click again on the map.

Here is a fiddle: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/z26sdh5s/5/)

The commented code below should be executed programmatically without user interaction, after pressing the draw button

```
    geometryFunction: function (c, g) {
        if (goog.isDef(g)) {
            g.setCoordinates(c);
        } else {
            // DO THIS AUTOMATICALLY ON PRESSING DRAW
            // TO INITIALIZE AND START THE DRAWING PROCESS
            c[0][0] = 1174072.754460305;
            c[0][1] = 332653.94709708635;
            g = new ol.geom.LineString(c);
        }
        ...
    }
```

The current behaviour is that you click on the Draw button and can click on the map to start drawing (but i overwrite the first node with my desired starting location -- in this example near central africa)

Is it possible to click on Draw and the first node is already programmatically set, without having to click on map first?

Comment: A while ago I was so desperate and did it using ol3 private method startDrawing_(). If you are interested I can share my code.

Comment: Yes i would be very interested in how you did that as it is a crucial functionality for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to do manually append points to the OpenLayers 3 `ol.interaction.Draw`, but it would make sense to be able to support it (in my mind).  It would be "as-if" the user had clicked.

You should ask the OL3-dev mailing this about adding such a feature to see what they think about it.  If they agree and you're willing to work on this, you could provide a pull request.  See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ol3-dev

Comment: Thanks that idea sounds very tempting (just took a look into source). I'm not sure about the general usefulness of such a scenario of injecting existing geometry into the Draw constructor, but it would be very important for the usecase i have. I have also some other issues like intercepting the click event in draw mode. Need to get a bigger picture to figure out whats the best solution.

Comment: Sure.  Don't hesitate to discuss this on the ol3-dev forum.  OL3 core devs might have good opinions on the matter.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a private method in OL you can do this to achieve what you want.

```
var event = $.Event('click'); //create a click event in your draw method using JQuery 
event.coordinate = [1174072.754460305,332653.94709708635];// set your starting coordinate
draw_interaction.startDrawing_(event);// tell your interaction to start drawing
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm! Would like to stick to the original code, but maybe your fix showed me a way to maybe implement it into OL3 in a clean way (if devs want it) -- Need to figure out now, how to prevent finishing of drawing, as long as no valid target feature is selected