# OpenLayers 6.5: Programmatically set coordinate of start draw

Tags: openlayers

I want to programmatically set the coordinate of the start of a user map draw (LineString), and then let the user continue drawing.

The reason I want to do this is that I want users to be able to draw a route on a map which is a combination of

- Them manually selecting line strings (e.g. over open mountain and to the next road) and then when they click a "snap" option,
- Snapping their route to OSM path/road geometries (my plan is to achieve this by sending the coordinate of the end of the current LineString along with the coordinate of where they next click to an OSRM server and get back GeoJSON)
- Then they may unclick "snap" and go back to freehand drawing.

So when I get the GeoJSON back, I need the next "un-snapped" line to start at exactly the same coordinate as the last point of the GeoJSON.

I know there is the Snap class in OpenLayers, but this requires the user to click the last point - I want the drawing to continue seamlessly.

4yrs ago, this question suggested a slightly hacky method of accessing OL private variables ([Open Layers 3 - Initialize Draw Interaction with first node on LineString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944733/open-layers-3-initialize-draw-interaction-with-first-node-on-linestring)).

I have tried this - basically it creates an event, sets the coordinates that forces the start draw to fire. However. this doesn't seem to work now, and I'm not keen on messing with OL internals, as that's always a fragile thing to do.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this "properly"?

Thanks!

Comment: Drawing can now be started by calling `appendCoordinates([[x, y]])` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Draw-Draw.html#appendCoordinates

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed - thank you very much!